# How to call Oracle function with EF 6 using Database First?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I'm looking to see how I can all an Oracle Function within Entity Framework. I've been doing some research but most info points to making sure the function is listed in the .edmx file. Thing is that I'm using the database first approach and with the Oracle drivers I can not see stored procs or function so I'm not using a .emdx file.

I found an article that showed to manually add the function to my DataContext file. I tried to follow along with this code but I get an error that it doesn't know "FunctionsConvention". This is what I put in my DataContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention("dbo", this.GetType()));
        }

        [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "LatLongDistanceCalc")]
        public static int LatLongDistanceCalc(int fromLat, int fromLong, int toLat, int toLong)
        {
            // no need to provide an implementation
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
```

Anyone know how I can add a function into my EF or maybe have a link to an article that would help out?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling the function as a select, returning a single result.  I have called quite complex functions with multiple parameters successfully.

```
public string ExecuteMyOracleFunction(string myParameter) {
  var command = @"select MyFunc(:my_param) from dual";
  using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(command, myParameter).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

The only issue I have had with this approach is with returning an Oracle `NUMBER`(without any precision specified).  This natively can overload a .NET decimal.